# Can the word "attaboy" be used in the context of humor or is it just offensive slang?

Tags: word-meaning, connotations

While watching a movie, I came across the expression "*attaboy*".
A quick search [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=attaboy) or on the web gave me the meaning, and roughly, the background. It's slang, it can probably be understood as sarcastic/cynical.

I wonder if there is some scorn in the word, if it's used only to show disdain (kind of an offensive word), or if it can be much "*lighter*" and used in a more light-hearted and humorous way. If I want to be mean/offensive, I use "*attaboy*", if I want to be nice, I use "*that's my boy*"?

Comment: **attaboy/attagirl** can be used sarcastically but  also used in praise.  The word is intoned very differently, depending on the intended meaning.  Compare **way to go**, which is similar in that regard.

Comment: The sarcastic intonation falls on the final syllable, the praise intonation has a lift on the final syllable.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know if it’s a generational thing (they so often are!) or a regional thing, but for this native speaker of American English the exclamations *attaboy* and *attagirl* are used at least as often literally—in praise—as sarcastically. And as nouns meaning an expression of praise, they are generally positive, though often of smallish magnitude. Thus nobody would characterize a Nobel Prize as an attagirl (except ironically and understatedly), but a sincere and kindly meant note from one’s boss could perfectly reasonably be characterized that way.

Comment: I've known it as praising/encouraging since the 1950s, in Britain, I guess it came across to the UK in films and TV.

Answer (score 1):

It's not offensive. It might be a little patronising. I can imagine it being used sarcastically - but almost anything can be sarcastic.

I don't detect any particular *scorn*.  But this is not a common enough phrase to be useful.  The only example I can think of is when Harry Potter's horrible aunt Marge uses "attaboy" to her brother to thank him for serving a particularly large brandy.  Aunt Marge is horrid, but she isn't being scornful of her (equally horrible) brother.

"That's my boy" is equally patronising.  The patronising aspect is the use of "boy".

Comment: "*The patronising aspect is the use of "boy".*" like the offensive word (boy) used towards colored person in the past? (I don't mean to misuse the word or offend anyone, please forgive me and tell me so that I can delete it).

Comment: I don't link "attaboy" with "boy" used in a racist way. But I'm not from America, and "boy" isn't used like that in my dialect (much(?)) I only link it with "boy" meaning "male child" and so somewhat patronising. Of course it is less patronising if used with an actual "boy".

Answer (score 0):

*Attaboy/attagirl* was originally an expression of praise. It's outdated, thus its use is typically taken as insincere. Furthermore, it would typically have been directed to someone much younger, thus it can easily come off as patronizing.

Neither of those points are significantly different between *attaboy* and *that's my boy*. If you want to praise someone sincerely, you should find a different expression, and if you want to make a joke, you can use either.

Comment: I still hear parents using it down at the playing fields at youth soccer and lacrosse games, and  at T-ball with the really young kids.

Comment: I've also heard parents shouting "*that's my boy*" to the public, to praise their kid. Seems pretty nice in my opinion.

Comment: @OldPadawan Sure, I think you're hearing it used literally, to inform onlookers that that's their kid. No doubt that's how the expression started, but the inflection has changed and the usage expanded.

Comment: I still have a problem with the intonation, like TimR explained in a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343930/can-the-word-attaboy-be-used-in-the-context-of-humor-or-is-it-just-offensive-s/343936#comment663436_343930). I'll keep listening and try and catch the tone. Anyway, thanks for the help.